# Tomcat response hanging when processing simple request for .JS file

Tags: tomcat, encoding, tomcat7, mime-types, mime

I have a JavaScript file on my Tomcat 7 server.

However, when I attempt to retrieve the file via HTTP GET, the response hangs and does not fully write the file to my client.  It writes about 80% of the file to my client then the response seems to hang.  I can't find anything in tomcat logs at this point.

It does not seem to be a browser issue, it hangs with wget, Chrome, Firefox and IE.

If I rename the file extension so that is detected as a different MIME type, it works and will download (e.g. rename to test.blah).  Note: .txt (plain/text) also fails.

I've noticed there is possibly some strange characters encoded into the file:

```
iconv -f ascii -t ascii jquery.jqplot.js  > test
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 321379
```

I have tried playing around with iconv to find and strip out any strange characters, but to no avail.

```
iconv f ascii -t ascii//IGNORE jquery.jqplot.js  > test   #still does not work)
```

The file is here:

http://www.tempsend.com/081FEAAA7F/D7C0/jquery.jqplot.js

- Note: if I change the mime-mapping in web.xml for "js" extensions from "application/javascript" to "application/octet-stream" it will download fine.

** Update:

I was able to reproduce it by dropping the file directly into webapps/ROOT/  and attempting to fetch it.  Details: RHELS 5.9 -tomcat 7.0.27 and also 7.0.52.

Also noticed this occurs ONLY when accessing the file REMOTELY over HTTP (it works over HTTPS or via localhost).  This is leading me to think it may be some strange intranet firewall issue.

Comment: the file is valid utf-8 accord to iconv, and the linux machine system default (which tomcat uses when reading static web resources) is also utf8

Comment: Exact Tomcat version? Have you got compression enabled? If so, what are the settings?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me without any problems on a clean Tomcat 7.0.53 install (using the RC since 7.0.53 hasn't been formally released as I write this).

The only issues I recall in the last few years relating to Tomcat and Javascript were to do with the user agents not recognising the mime-type.

I've checked this with compression as well and it still works.

Therefore, it is likely to be something your application is doing. I'd suggest looking at filters and any servlet configured to serve javascript and/or static resources.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it by dropping the file directly into webapps/ROOT/  and attempting to fetch it on RHELS 5.9.  Tested with tomcat 7.0.27 and also 7.0.52